# Is there any example show how to monitor tcp connection by heartbeat between android client and remote server?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, netty

I am looking for a example to show how to implement a reliable way to keep monitor the tcp connection between the android app and remote server by exchange heartbeat package.

Anyone know is there any existing example for this?

PS,I am using Netty for my server. and android use the pure socket.